# getbackstackentrycount after remove fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

when i remove an specific fragment from backstack the `getbackstackentrycount()` not refresh but the fragment successfully delete!
my code for test is here:

```
int count = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();
fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.remove(fragcontent);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
//also I add here this code => fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
//but count not getBackStackEntryCount() return previous count!
int newCount = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();
```

I very goggled for this but not solved.

Comment: What you want to do exactly?

Comment: I want to know count of fragments in stack. if count of them was <1 then finish activity.

Comment: Probably your method is not right. what is the scenario you are following?

Comment: for example i first add A fragment then add B fragment and when i want add A fragment again, first remove A from stack then add that on top of stack. for exit activity I override the `onBackPressed()` function and inside that if `getBackStackEntryCount()==1` then finish activity else I call `super.onBackPressed()`

Comment: `replace` fragment **A** with **B** using `.addToBackStack(null)` during the fragment transaction, then just use `onBackPressed()`.

Comment: I use `addToBackStack(null)` but when B fragment and A fragment popup from stack an empty page showing and when I click back again the activity finish!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you might want to do is the following:

**Activity** :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ...
    getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new OnBackStackChangedListener()
    {
        public void onBackStackChanged()
        {
            int backCount = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
            if (backCount == 0)
            {
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
```

For which to work, you need to add the fragments to backstack:

```
        getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
```

Comment: when I add A fragment and then B fragment then click back the `backCount` value is 2 and when click back again `backCount` is 1 but no fragment in activity!! . and click back again the activity finish.

Comment: are you using **replace** and **onBackPressed** ?

Comment: when I am user `replace` instead of `add` the `fragmentManager.remove(frg)` not remove the `frg`(A or B fragment)

Comment: You need to specify the container of the fragment, by default the id of the  fragment container layout.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is not right. You should do something like this in your activity.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        final Fragment fragment = this.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.main_frame);
        if (fragment != null && fragment instanceof FragmentB)
        {
            // Replace it with FragmentA
        }
        else
        {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you sure he needs to manually replace? If he used `addToBackStack(null)` at time of `replace`, going back makes him go to the previous one.

Comment: I'm not sure, In case he didn't add it to back stack he needs to replace it. Actually, this is general idea. He can definitely change it based on the implementation.

Comment: I want to know count of not removed fragment in backstack of fragmentManager. if count of them==1 then finish activity